# Group user likes based on page category

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way by which we can group user’s facebook likes based on the category of the pages, when I request from Graph API `/[user-id]?fields=likes` what I get is array of user’s likes in reverse chronological order. I need to group these likes based on the page’s category like Entertainer, Comedians, Celebrity, Artist, Actor/Director, etc categories should be grouped in a one category (say Personalities) and other pages like TV Show, Movie, TV Series, etc to be grouped in other category (let’s say Movies)

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to do any sorting on your own, after getting all the entries. You can use paging to get all entries: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: Hmm. Sorting different categories would be a very costly task when the user will have lots of likes

Comment: depends on the programming. it´s a very basic task and should not be very "costly" ;) - also, you can do it client side with the js sdk. it´s a simple loop, nothing else.